# Проводник в браузере

Tags: javascript, php

Всем привет.
Имею небольшой проводник который выводит в браузер список папок и файлов. Так же осуществляется переход между папками. Работает через аякс. На сервере всё обрабатывается)

```
foldername = document.getElementById('folder');
function listdir(){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', 'App.php', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send("folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            //window.location.pathname = 'list';
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

Когда я перехожу в подпапки то url не меняется, соответственно я не могу вернутся в браузере на уровень выше(клик по кн. назад). Думал менять window.location - не помогло. У кого есть какие идеи?

Comment: `history.pushState` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: history.pushState('', '', 'item'); - не пойму что передать в качестве первого параметра.